# Get IPv4 Address in Angular using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, ip, ipv4

I am looking for a way to get IPv4 Address in Angular 7 or greater. I need to identify user that has opened an app in browser by local IP address since the public IP is usually the same for all users in one company.

I tried this example here on the [link](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50891102.shtml) and some more, but no success so far. Do you have any idea for me? Is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with ng only. You need access to the request object of page angular is loaded on. For that you need to write some server code.

If you're on node.js try using [geoip-lite](https://github.com/geoip-lite/node-geoip) and then write a GET endpoint that uses the `x-forwarded-for` header and as fallback uses the requester's ip via `req.connection.remoteAddress.split(":")[3]`

Then you can return that results to the ng app via

```
const ip = xForwadedFor || remoteIP;
const geo = geoip.lookup(ip);
```

Then you need to consume the results from the GET endpoint through the http service of ng.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Will try and see what happens.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, but no success. I totally changed approach later.

Comment: Strange, i have done that fort the past 10 years time and time again and it always works. Maybe you expected it to work locally on your machine without being deployed?

Comment: @makeitmorehuman Can you please elaborate your answer? Such as- how to import geoip lite to my component and where the xForwadedFor need to be executed?

Comment: https://github.com/geoip-lite/node-geoip#synopsis